# How do I set options for the Selenium MS Edge driver in ruby?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

I am trying to open a browser with the Selenium::WebDriver::Edge::Driver on Windows. I am able to open the browser but my session immediately crashes with this error:

```
unknown command: Cannot call non W3C standard command while in W3C mode 
(Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownCommandError)
```

How would I turn off W3C mode in selenium ruby? I have tried to follow the docs [here](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/selenium-webdriver/Selenium/WebDriver/Edge/Options) by doing:

```
webdriver_options = Selenium::WebDriver::Edge::Options.new(opts: {w3c: false})
```

before instantiating the webdriver. However this does not seem to make a difference - I suspect I am setting the options wrong. Has anyone seen this issue before? Thanks.

Comment: Which version of Edge browser are you using? The Edge Legacy or the Edge Chromium browser? I'm not familar with ruby but I find some similar threads. You could refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56452798/how-to-turn-off-w3c-in-chromedriver-to-address-the-error-unknown-command-cannot). If you're using Edge Chromium, I think the options are like the Chrome's. You could try something like `capabilities = { "edgeOptions" => {'w3c' => false} }` or `options = Selenium::WebDriver::Edge::Options.new`, `options.add_option('w3c', false)`.

Comment: @YuZhou thanks! adding capabilities = { "edgeOptions" => {'w3c' => false} } and then passing it into the driver fixed my issue

Comment: That's great! I want to put it as an answer and hope you can mark it as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Edge Chromium, I think the options are like the Chrome's. You could refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56452798/how-to-turn-off-w3c-in-chromedriver-to-address-the-error-unknown-command-cannot) and add the following code then pass it into the driver:

```
capabilities = { "edgeOptions" => {'w3c' => false} }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. verify if your browser is up to date
2. Start > Settings > System > About; - and verify OS build
3. Download last driver: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/
4. Unzip las version on: C:\Ruby23-x64\bin;
5. If you are using capybara, try this:

   Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|

   Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :edge)

   end