# Turning off w3c permanently on msedgedriver.exe

Tags: selenium, webdriver, microsoft-edge, watir

My organization, just upgraded to Version 81.0.416.53 (Official build) (64-bit) of the edge chromium browser and I am the automation engineer for it. I am having issues getting my version of Watir/Ruby to work with it I have updated the Edge Webdriver to match the version number of the browser. I was originally using the Chrome class to interact with chromium, now that no longer works, but when I switch to Edge I keep getting a w3c error when I attempt to run my ui automation scripts. There doesn't appear to be a way for me to programatically turn off the Hardware acceleration for the webdriver through the Edge class in Watir/Selenium. I have turned it off for my browser, but when I run the webdriver, it is still turned on. Is there any way for me to make this change directly in the webdriver instead of trying to change an option that doesn't exist in Watir?

I am open to other suggestions if you have them. Thank You for your time.

System:

- ruby 2.5.8p224 (2020-03-31 revision 67882) [x64-mingw32]
- watir(6.16.5)
- selenium-webdriver (3.142.7)
- Edge Chromium Version 81.0.416.53 (Official build) (64-bit)
- Windows 10

Code:

```
require 'watir'
Selenium::WebDriver::Edge::Service.driver_path = "c:/webdriver_location/msedgedriver.exe"
client = :edge
browser = Watir::Browser.new(client)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60940488/how-do-i-set-options-for-the-selenium-ms-edge-driver-in-ruby/60982929#60982929) before. You could use the options like Chrome's in Edge Chromium. The code in ruby is like the following:

```
capabilities = { "edgeOptions" => {'w3c' => false} }
```

I'm not familiar with Watir, don't know if this syntax can be used in Watir. You could change it into the usable one in Watir.

For more detailed information, you could also refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56452798/how-to-turn-off-w3c-in-chromedriver-to-address-the-error-unknown-command-cannot).

Comment: That got me beyond the w3c issue, now I am having a separate issue getting:       javascript error: Cannot read property 'cssText' of undefined I will open a separate ticket for this, can't seem to find anything about how I am getting this error, but I am assuming that it has something to do with the hardware acceleration being turned off.