# Rails update from chromedriver-helper to webdriver shows W3C standard error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I updated my app to `webdriver` from `chromedriver-helper` but after that my I've received errors in my specs. It fails in several cases with the same error

> Failure/Error: Unable to infer file and line number from backtrace
>   Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownCommandError:
>           unknown command: Cannot call non W3C standard command while in W3C mode

I followed this guide https://everydayrails.com/2019/04/09/chromedriver-helper-webdrivers.html but there are no single word about it. I think it's quite similar issue with this one [Cannot call non W3C standard command while in W3C mode (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownCommandError) with Selenium ChromeDriver in Cucumber Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56111529/cannot-call-non-w3c-standard-command-while-in-w3c-mode-seleniumwebdrivererr) but I don't see any relevant answer for that (they don't switched `chromedriver-helper` to `webdriver` actually)

`gemfile.rb`

```
group :development, :test do
  gem "awesome_print", require: "ap"
  gem "capybara"
  gem "webdrivers"
  gem "factory_bot_rails"
  gem "faraday-detailed_logger"
  gem "pry"
  gem "rspec-rails"
  gem "site_prism"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating `capybara` to the latest version (if it's not already) and see if that helps. I saw a similar issues after moving from `chromedriver-helper` to `webdrivers`, and updating `capybara` to `3.15.1` resolved them.

Comment: You mean `3.5.1` - I'm using this version, unfortunately it's not an issue

Comment: No, I meant https://rubygems.org/gems/capybara/versions/3.15.1. You can try and update to latest version too - https://rubygems.org/gems/capybara/versions.

Comment: For it to work I had to update `site_prism` to newest version but after that it works, thanks a lot!