# How to resolve "Cannot call non W3C standard command while in W3C mode" in case of automating android webView

Tags: java, android, appium

I am doing an android webView automation. After changing from native app context to webview context, I am getting the following error.

```
org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: unknown command: Cannot call non W3C standard command while in W3C mode
```

There are many similar questions related to this but all are related to web. I couldn't find any solution to solve this in android webView. Can anyone please let me know how can I solve this.

Environment:

1. Mobile version : 5.1.1
2. Appium Version 1.15.1
3. chromeDriver version : 78.0.3904.70
4. Chrome Verison : 78.0.3904.62

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56111529/cannot-call-non-w3c-standard-command-while-in-w3c-mode-seleniumwebdrivererr?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Hi @hfarhanahmed, I already saw this answer and try to use it but I failed. That answer is implemented from Web application. But I am trying to automate android Hybrid app (which has webview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found the solution. I just used the below capabilities.

```
capabilities.setCapability("appium:chromeOptions", ImmutableMap.of("w3c", false));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar challenge. Additionally in my case this log message appeared when I had set capabilities like this:

```
caps.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.FORCE_MJSONWP, true);
```

The situation is connected with Mobile JSON Wire Protocole I quess.